# Architecture Copmonents. In which order called lifecycle events?

Tags: android, architecture, android-lifecycle, observer-pattern, android-architecture-components

For example, we have

```
 class A implements LifecycleObserver{
        @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
        public void create() {

        }
    }
```

and also classes B and C, which are same.

Q:Is there guarantee, that all of the methods `create` will be called in such order, as we registered LifecycleObservers?

```
    getLifecycle().addObserver(new A());
    getLifecycle().addObserver(new B());
    getLifecycle().addObserver(new C());
```

Answer (score 2):

The class [LifecycleRegistry](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleRegistry.html) which is the only one known direct subclass of [Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Lifecycle.html), in realization of the method [addObserver()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleRegistry.html#addObserver(android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver)) uses FastSafeIterableMap which under hood uses a regular HashMap where a key is your implementation of the [LifecycleObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleObserver.html). 
So answering your question, an order will be as documented [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time.

Comment: So is the answer no, the order of lifecycle calls is not linear to `addObserver` calls?